# How is memory managed in distributed runtime in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-flink, distributed-caching

We are building an Apache Flink based data stream processing application in Java 8. We need to maintain a state-full list of objects which characteristics are updated every ten seconds via a source stream.

By specs we must use, if possible, no distributed storage. So, my question is about Flink's memory manager: in a cluster configuration, does it replicate the memory used by a task-manager? Or is there any way to use a distributed in-memory solution with Flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Flink [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/state.html). This way you can store it in flink's state which will be integrated with internal mechanisms like checkpointing/savepointing etc.

If you need to query it externally from other services a [queryable state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/queryable_state.html) can be a good addition.

Comment: Thx Dawid! It helped a lot!